# My app-debug file is there but shows me an error

Tags: android

[image: Here in the finder window you can see that the app-debug.apk file is there but then the event log says that it is missing??]

Here in the finder window you can see that the app-debug.apk file is there but then the event log says that it is missing??

Comment: clean & rebuild your project

Comment: what....why?? should I is there any other way out??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For these types of issues you can often fix them by using (File --> Invalidate catches / Restart)

If it still does not work you can try deleting the apk folder,
it will regenerate when you rebuild the app.

if this still does not work you may have to try reinstalling android studio.

Comment: hey this thingy doesn't work

Comment: i gave you 3 options what one doesnt work and what is the error, be more spesific so i can help

Comment: I just answered my own question.....Basically my app name was "Help&About", so the & was not allowed and that was the mistake  :)

Comment: awsome it works now good luck with the project